# Definition of weakly continuous map from one Banach space to another

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, weak-convergence

What is the definition of a weakly continuous function from a Banach space to a Banach space?

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces. Define $f : X \rightarrow Y$ as a function. Am I right to say that $f$ is weakly continuous if the net $x_{\alpha} \rightarrow x$ in the weak topology of $X$, then $f(x_\alpha) \rightarrow f(x)$ in the weak topology of $Y$?

I know that we cannot change the net into a sequence, as some Banach spaces are Schur spaces, which have the property that every weakly convergent is norm convergent.

If my definition is not correct, then may I know what is the proper definition?

Remark: Sorry for the confusion. I am talking about weak-to-weak continuous.

Comment: Any one of the equivalent definitions of a continuous function between two topological spaces is sufficient, including the one you list above. The pre-image of weakly open sets being weakly open would also be sufficient, for example. Of course, if your function is linear you can perhaps use the fact that functionals are mapped to functionals to your advantage.

Answer (score 6):

Both  topologies matter: one on the domain, the other on the target space. Thus, one can speak of

- weak-weak continuity: the preimage of a weakly open set in $Y$ is weakly open in $X$.
- weak-strong continuity: the preimage of an open set in $Y$ is weakly  open in $X$.
- strong-weak continuity: the preimage of a weakly open set in $Y$ is   open in $X$.

The first one is often used: e.g., every continuous linear operator is weak-weak continuous. But so is the second: finite rank operators are weak-strong continuous. Also,  compact linear operator is weak-strong continuous on bounded sets. I don't remember ever reading about strong-weak continuity, it's included just for completeness.

If you simply say "weakly continuous from $X$ to $Y$", the reader will have to pause and guess your intention. Try to make it clear from context which version you are using.